# bash how to get async command output to variable

Tags: linux, bash

i want to know how can we get command output to variable in bash

here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
opt="svcrack -v -u100 -r1-9999 -z3 10.0.0.1"
opt2="$($opt)"

echo "myout output $opt2"
```

output

```
myout output
```

not working inside function :(

```
function zwork(){

opt=$(svcrack -v -u100 -r1-9999 -z3 10.0.0.1 2>&1)

echo "myout output $opt"
}

out=$(zwork)
```

Comment: I don't see anything asynchronous in your script. If that's the output you get, then your command just has no output on stdout.

Comment: it have output , svcrack is python script

Comment: I said no output on stdout. Judging from your "it worked" comment below, the output is on stderr, which doesn't contradict my diagnosis. But you should see output on stderr printed nevertheless if you're running the exact script as above in an interactive shell.

Comment: As an aside, variables are for data, not code. Either define a function named `opt`, or use the `svcrack` command directly in the command substitution as in the accepted answer. See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Came late, but I guess you had to declare your function just as `zwork(){ ... }` instead of `function zwork(){ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try redirecting stderr to stdout like:

```
#!/bin/bash
opt=$(svcrack -v -u100 -r1-9999 -z3 10.0.0.1 2>&1)

echo "myout output $opt"
```

Here you can read more about [command substition](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: sir can u please check , its not working inside function , question update

Answer (score 0):

If you store a command in a variable in bash you need to use the ***eval*** keyword to execute that command.
So in your case you should do something like this...

```
opt="svcrack -v -u100 -r1-9999 -z3 10.0.0.1"
opt2=$(eval $opt)
echo "myout output $opt2"
```

Correction : I was testing this in ZSH (not pure bash), so i needed to add the ***eval*** and ended up assuming that is the missing bit. However as someone corrected me in comment. That is not necessary.

Only problem in the OP script was

```
opt2="$($opt)"
```

it should have been

```
opt2=$($opt)
```

Comment: Not true. Parameter expansion goes before command substitution, so the original script is valid, albeit quite stupid.